# Qt/c++ random string generation

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating an application where I need to generate multiple random strings, almost like a unique ID that is made up of ASCII characters of a certain length that have a mix of uppercase/lowercase/numerical characters.

Are there any Qt libraries for achieving this? If not, what are some of the preferred ways of generating multiple random strings in pure c++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a random string or number in Qt4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244999/create-a-random-string-or-number-in-qt4) also see [How do I create a random alpha-numeric string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c)

Answer (score 29):

You could write a function like this:

```
QString GetRandomString() const
{
   const QString possibleCharacters("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
   const int randomStringLength = 12; // assuming you want random strings of 12 characters

   QString randomString;
   for(int i=0; i<randomStringLength; ++i)
   {
       int index = qrand() % possibleCharacters.length();
       QChar nextChar = possibleCharacters.at(index);
       randomString.append(nextChar);
   }
   return randomString;
}
```

Comment: Very great solution, although I'm having a problem where the answer isn't random each time I run the program (even after closing and opening QT Creator)...  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @BarryDoyle, you may need to seed the random number generator with qsrand http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qsrand

Comment: I figured it out and that was the issue, thanks...

Comment: Way shorter without putting the 2x26 Characters in the stack: `randomString.append('A'+(qrand()%(2*26));` just using old school char-arithmetics and the fact that all the characters are following the **A** in ASCII