# QT: AES-256-CBC Encrypt/Decript in C++ according to PHP Code

Tags: php, c++, qt, qml, aes

I have a simple PHP Code for encryption/decription AES-256-CBC:

```
function safeEncrypt($token) {
    $enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length("aes-256-cbc"));
    return openssl_encrypt($token, "aes-256-cbc", "passToCrypt", 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
}
function safeDecrypt($token) {
    $enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length("aes-256-cbc"));
    list($token, $enc_iv) = explode("::", $token);
    return openssl_decrypt($token, "aes-256-cbc", "passToCrypt", 0, hex2bin($enc_iv));
}
```

and I am looking for the SAME way for c++ inside QML app.
So far I have this (I dont know how to handle the IV)

cryption.h:

```
#ifndef CRYPTION_H
#define CRYPTION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QCryptographicHash>

class Cryption : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Cryption(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString encrypt(QString strToEncrypt);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString decrypt(QString strToDecrypt);

private:
    QString method;
    QString key;
    QAESEncryption encryption(QAESEncryption::AES_256, QAESEncryption::CBC);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // CRYPTION_H
```

cryption.cpp:

```
#include "cryption.h"
#include <QCryptographicHash>

Cryption::Cryption(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // Main Settings
    method = "aes-256-cbc";
    key = "passToCrypt";
}

QString Cryption::encrypt(QString strToEncrypt)
{
    QByteArray hashKey = QCryptographicHash::hash(key.toLocal8Bit(), QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
//  QByteArray hashIV = QCryptographicHash::hash(iv.toLocal8Bit(), QCryptographicHash::Md5);

    QByteArray encodeText = encryption.encode(strToEncrypt.toLocal8Bit(), hashKey, hashIV);
    return encodeText;
}

QString Cryption::decrypt(QString strToEncrypt)
{
    QByteArray hashKey = QCryptographicHash::hash(key.toLocal8Bit(), QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
//  QByteArray hashIV = QCryptographicHash::hash(iv.toLocal8Bit(), QCryptographicHash::Md5);

    QByteArray decodeText = encryption.decode(encodeText, hashKey, hashIV);
    QString decodedString = QString(encryption.removePadding(decodeText));
    return decodedString;
}
```

can you help me finish it please?
Main thing is that I dont know how to handle the IV as the PHP does (some random number, hex2bin) and the IV is saved into the encoded string (ENCODED_STRING::USED_IV) so the IV can be later on used for decoding

Comment: OT: Funny how in Qt _MD5: is called a _cryptographic hash_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code, the [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (IV) is generated with a random number generator. You may do the same with Qt. For instance:

```
QByteArray iv = QByteArray(16, 0);
for(int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
    iv[i] = static_cast<char>(QRandomGenerator::system()->bounded(255));
}
```

Instead, the [example](https://github.com/bricke/Qt-AES#example) you are following creates a string with whatever arbitrary text, and then calculates a MD5 hash of it. Using the above method is more direct, but you can do the same or [generate a random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244999/create-a-random-string-or-number-in-qt4) before calculating the hash.